# How can pyautogui.pixelMatchesColor not work properly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, colors, pyautogui, pixelmatch

```
def perfect_click(name):    # Performs a click after checking for loaded image
    location = None
    image_file = name

    while location is None:
        try:
            location = pyautogui.locateOnScreen(image_file)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

    coordinates = pyautogui.center(location)
    x, y = coordinates
    print(coordinates)
    pixel = False
    while pixel is False:
        try:
            pixel = pyautogui.pixelMatchesColor(coordinates, (241, 63, 83), tolerance=10)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
    pyautogui.click(coordinates)
```

I'm trying to create a function that checks for a button and waits till the button is clickable and then click it and to accomplish this I've tried to use pixel matching and unclickable buttons are just a lil lighter shade in colour.. atleast it is in my case and locate on screen dosen't detect it.

here is the error:

```
pixelMatchesColor() missing 1 required positional argument: 'expectedRGBColor'
```

I know what your reaction will be "well its as its says
its missing 'expectedRGBColor'"

But the thing is it's not getting outta loop even after the button matches.
I tried playing with tolerance it's not working either.

I ran the program to print coordinates but it's not printing x and y coordinates only in this function, works just fine in other function where it's just looping till it finds the image and clicks it.
It's not giving an error for missing coordinates

can anyone please please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

`pixelMatchesColor` is looking for `(x, y, expectedRGBColor, tolerance)`

Your `coordinates` variable is 2 points, but you are putting it only in the first parameter. The `x` and `y` you assign from it in `x, y = coordinates` would be perfectly suited for `pixelMatchesColor`.

Try this

```
pixel = pyautogui.pixelMatchesColor(x, y, (241, 63, 83), tolerance=10)
```

Comment: I tried your solution @Matt M but it's giving me this error now:

Comment: ```argument 2: <class 'TypeError'>: Don't know how to convert parameter 2```

Comment: That's odd, I tried this myself. Try `print(x)` and `print(y)` before the error line and see what it outputs. Also, you can try `co1 = coordinates[0]` and `co2 = coordinates[1]` and then `...pixelMatchesColor(co1, co2, (241....` and see if that works. Also try `print(coordinates)` before the error line and let me know what you get

Comment: I tried print(coordinates) before.. returns nothing.

Comment: ```argument 2: <class 'TypeError'>: Don't know how to convert parameter 2
Point(x=333, y=649)```

Comment: it's printing coordinates now

Comment: parameter 2 is value of r, g, b if I'm not wrong. I think somethings wrong there.

Comment: Try the co1 and co2 thing i typed. Parameter 2 is supposed to be an integer, just like Parameter 1. Also print co1 and co2 if it doesnt work so i know what the values are

Comment: ```argument 2: <class 'TypeError'>: Don't know how to convert parameter 2
Point(x=333, y=649)
333
649```

Comment: also what I've noticed is It gives the error just when the button is available to click

Comment: hey, figured it out! I changed the loop like such and it worked: ``` pixel = True
    while pixel is not True:```

Comment: Oh great, glad you figured it out

Answer (score 0):

Just to mention that for `location = pyautogui.locateOnScreen()` function
itself will return a `numpy.intc` (you can look at it at type(x)).
To make `pyautogui.pixelMatchesColor()` you need to convert `numpy.intc` to `int`.